# How can I make a copy of a sub-folder into a separate repository in Git?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree, git-filter-branch

I have the following repository `foo.git` with the following sub-folders.

```
/foo
----/bar1
----/bar2
```

I want to create a new separate repository `bar1.git` along with its commit history, with two copies of the contents now -  at `bar1.git` and `foo.git/bar1`.

Also, what would be a good way to merge back the updated contents of `bar1.git` with `foo.git/bar1` at a later point of time with the new commit history retained?

I am aware of `subtree`, `submodule` and `filter-branch` commands but not sure which one and how exactly to use them in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+detach+directory

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [git-submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is the following:

1. Create `bar1.git` repository
2. Go to your local `foo` repository and add git-submodule inside with a command:

   ```
   git submodule add -b master https://github.com/user/bar1.git bar1
   ```
3. Update git-submodule with a command:

   ```
   git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
   ```

   Use this command after any new clone `foo` repository as well.
4. You'll see `.gitmodules` file with content similar to:

   ```
   [submodule "bar1"]
   path = bar1
   url = https://github.com/user/bar1.git
   branch = master
   ```
5. Commit and pull your changes in `foo` repository
6. If you make any changes to `bar1` repository you need to sync it with your `foo\bar1` submodule. This can be done with set of commands:

   ```
   git pull
   git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
   git pull --recurse-submodules
   git submodule foreach "(git checkout master; git pull)"
   git add --all
   git commit -m "Submodule Sync"
   git push
   ```

   This command will recursively update and sync ALL submodules in `foo` repository to the latest revision in `master` branch.